# How to get ssid and password of my hotspot to share with receiver?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My problem is how to get ssid and password of my hotspot to share with receiver ?

Hello I am developing app in xamarin forms to share files with each other.
I got success to turn on and off wifi and hotspot.
But when i turn on hotspot it turn on hotspot with different ssid and password which i want to know and turn it into barcode so receiver will scan code and connect to hotspot and share files.
My code runs very well but don't know how to solve this  problem.

Comment: Hi, could you share the code of opening hotspot? I will check that in my local site.

Comment: My Code

`public WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation Mreservation { get; set; }

WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);
WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback callback = new WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback();
wifi.StartLocalOnlyHotspot(callback, new Handler());`

Answer (score 0):

You could custom the **WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback**, and there is a [onStarted](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback#onStarted(android.net.wifi.WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation)) method that can get `WifiConfiguration`. Then we can get the `SSID` and `Password` now.

For example, **CustomWifiManagerCallback** class as follows:

```
public class CustomWifiManagerCallback: WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotCallback
{
    private const string TAG = nameof(myWifiManagerCallback);

    private MainActivity mainActivity;

    public CustomWifiManagerCallback(Activity _activity)
    {
        if (_activity.GetType() == typeof(MainActivity))
            mainActivity = (MainActivity)_activity;
    }

    public override void OnStarted(WifiManager.LocalOnlyHotspotReservation reservation)
    {
        base.OnStarted(reservation);
        Console.WriteLine( "Wifi Hotspot is on now");

        var ssid = reservation.WifiConfiguration.Ssid;
        var pwd = reservation.WifiConfiguration.PreSharedKey;
        Console.WriteLine("started SSID:" + ssid + " password:"+ pwd);
        mainActivity.Mreservation = reservation;
    }

    public override void OnFailed([GeneratedEnum] LocalOnlyHotspotCallbackErrorCode reason)
    {
        base.OnFailed(reason);
        Console.WriteLine( "onStopped: ");
    }

    public override void OnStopped()
    {
        base.OnStopped();
        Console.WriteLine( "onFailed: ");
    }
}
```

Now we can start as follows:

```
WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Context.WifiService);  
wifi.StartLocalOnlyHotspot(new CustomWifiManagerCallback(this), new Handler());
```